# fseek() giving 2 different counts when I expected the same count

Tags: c, fseek

If I use

```
fseek(file_ptr, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(file_ptr);
```

I get `480000` which is right as I have `60000` x `double float` at 8 bytes per `double` in the file.

But when I use

```
fseek(file_ptr, sizeof(double), SEEK_END);
size = ftell(file_ptr);
```

I get `480008` an extra 8 bytes. Anyone know what they are?

Comment: `sizeof(double)` is not the same as `0`, so why do you expect the same result??

Comment: Most filesystems support seeking beyond the end of a file. That can either enlarge the file, or add a *hole*.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I expected both to move to the end of the file

Comment: @DrBwts Which manual page for `fseek` did you use? What is your target platform? It may be good to try to get that manual page for `fseek` updated if it's wrong - or it's not the correct manual page for your target platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I use

```
fseek(file_ptr, sizeof(double), SEEK_END);
size = ftell(file_ptr);
```

> I get 480008 an extra 8 bytes

That is because the size of a `double` on your system is 8 bytes, and `fseek()` set the file position indicator 8 bytes from `SEEK_END`.

> The new position, measured in bytes, is obtained by adding offset
> bytes to the position specified by whence.

---

Re:

> Anyone know what they are?

This is what the open group's manual page has to say about it:

> The fseek() function shall allow the file-position indicator to be set
> beyond the end of existing data in the file. If data is later written
> at this point, subsequent reads of data in the gap shall return bytes
> with the value 0 until data is actually written into the gap.
>
> The behavior of fseek() on devices which are incapable of seeking is
> implementation-defined. The value of the file offset associated with
> such a device is undefined.

Note that this behaviour is only specified for POSIX-compliant systems.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in [`fseek()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) man page (Linux OS).

The function prototype is

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
```

where `offset` parameter is described as follows

> The new position, measured in bytes, is obtained by adding offset bytes to the position specified by `whence`.

Since your offset is 8 (`sizeof double`, in your system) and the original file size is 480000, that's why you get 480008.

The manual never mention any limitation preventing the pointer to be set after `SEEK_END`.